# Disable cache for Docker compose

Tags: docker, caching, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've met the case where Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM image with fully-configured server (without application)
COPY war created locally by IntelliJ inside server in Docker image
```

Basically every time when I'm starting container with this Dockerfile, Docker creates new image. Because this `.war` file is changing often (this is the whole purpose of using Docker here - for easy deploying .war images during development), I've a lot of not used images with older versions of this application. This causes space on disk problems and I have to manually prune all deprecated images.

Is there any way to *disable* Docker caching? I'm using a set of servers connected by docker-compose file, so maybe it can somehow manage those images to automatically remove them when it is not needed anymore?

`docker build` has `--no-cache` parameter, but it only invalidates cache for every layer (every command is always executed, but still saved inside images/layers repository). Also `--force-rm` is not working for me.

Comment: I am not sure you already know how to remove dangling image, but I hope 
 it would be a little help, here is to remove dangling image `docker rmi $(docker images -aq -f dangling=true)`

Answer (score 0):

as [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache) says, if the file change on every docker build the cache will be ignored because the checksum file change, maybe you have to remove the COPY command from the Dockerfile and use a [VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) and copy the war file on every docker run to ensure that war will change on every start

Comment: Well, on Windows 7 os it isn't so easy to create volume, but idea seems fine. Docker should really have better managing for dangling images...

Comment: Maybe you should look into using a bind mount to bring a local directory into the container at runtime, that way you can simply update the .war file in that directory and the container will see it.

Comment: ... NOTE, you may need to use the COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS env var with this:  https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_convert_windows_paths